# Designing Corda Doorman Service

Tags: corda

Where can I find detailed tutorial for corda doorman? I have gone through corda official documentation but couldn't find detailed steps to implement doorman service.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a doorman service requires a good understanding of the Corda ecosystem. It is not as simple as following a few steps and it would be ready to use.

At a high level though it needs to run three major services:

- **Identity Manager Service** - To allow nodes to join the network and handle revocation of a nodes certificate
- **Network Map Service** - Provides a global view of the network
- **Signing Services** - Provides a way to sign approved requests to join the network (CSRs) or revoke a certificate (CRRs) as well as changes to the network map

We have the CENM (Corda Enterprise Network Manager) which is our enterprise offering of a doorman.

You may choose to use some opensource doorman like cordite, which may have some limited functionality but would work depending on how much flexibility your network demands.

Comment: Thanks.Where can I find samples/examples that demonstrates use of CENM/cordite doorman services?

Comment: Samples/example which will demonstrate using these services to build doorman servers

Comment: Here are the CENM docs: https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.2.html and here cordite NMS repo: https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service